# How to start a Powershell session with all my modules imported?

Tags: .net, powershell, powershell-3.0

I have many modules to make my life easier stored in a particular folder.

**QUESTION**:
What is the best practice to start a Powerhsell session that has all those modules imported and the functions ready to be used?

Thanks!

Comment: Add them through Import-Module in your profile.ps1 file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can create a profile on a network share `\\server\share\commonProfile.ps1`
in that profile you define your module path to the shared folder

```
if($env:PSModulePath -match "\\\\server\\share\\modules" -eq $false){
    $env:PSModulePath = $env:PSModulePath + ";\\server\share\Modules"
}
```

Copy your modules to `\\server\share\Modules`,
now you should be able to do

```
$rs=new-pssession $computername
icm -Session $rs -ScriptBlock{. \\server\share\commonProfile.ps1} #dot source the profile
etsn $rs #enter remote session

#your modules should now be availables in the remote session :
get-module -listavailable
```

Comment: icm is a short-cut for...?